# How to make globe method for custom button action in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, swift5

I have a sign in screen in which two fields are there password and email textfield.
I added both textfield with stackview. After adding textfields, I need to add button of password lock. After clicking on password lock button user can see the password. I took button from library and try to add on textfield but, due to stackview it always set as third element for stackview. So I am unable to add.
So I decided to add with extension of textfield. So i added button successfully in utility class,
but unable to add action with selector. It showing an error

> Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'passwordAction'

My code for add button is

```
extension UITextField {

func passwordButton(vc:UIViewController){
    let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 25, width: 24, height: 17))
    let passwordButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 17))
    passwordButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "show_password"), for: .normal)
    passwordButton.addTarget(vc, action: #selector(vc.passwordAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    paddingView.addSubview(passwordButton)
    self.addSubview(paddingView)
}
}
class Loginviewcontroller{
   passwordTextField.passwordButton(vc: self)
 func passwordAction(){
  print("action")
 }
 }
```

I am calling this method from login controller.

So I have two question:-

1. when two textfield are attached with stackview, we can not put button on textfield with storyboard?
2. How can I make globle method to add button and add action that can access in uiviewcontroller?

Comment: There are various way to do this... are you sure you want to "reinvent the wheel"? I'd suggest searching for `swift uitextfield show hide password` and see if one of the many existing methods would work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is self explanatory, you added the `passwordAction` method to `Loginviewcontroller` but in `func passwordButton` you take a `UIViewController` as an argument. As a result even when you pass instance of `Loginviewcontroller` to `passwordButton` function call, in the function scope `vc` is just another `UIViewController` and clearly all `UIViewController`s does not have a method named `passwordAction`.

As you said you wanna make global method to add button and add action that can access in **uiviewcontroller** you can follow below approach

**Step 1:** Declare a protocol

```
@objc protocol SecureTextProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func passwordAction()
}
```

**Step 2:** Update your `passwordButton` method to take `SecureTextProtocol` instead of plain `UIViewController`

```
extension UITextField {

    func passwordButton(vc:SecureTextProtocol){
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 25, width: 24, height: 17))
        let passwordButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 17))
        passwordButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "show_password"), for: .normal)
        passwordButton.addTarget(vc, action: #selector(vc.passwordAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        paddingView.addSubview(passwordButton)
        self.addSubview(paddingView)
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Make your ViewController's that want to get the button action to confirm to `SecureTextProtocol` protocol

```
class Loginviewcontroller: UIViewController, SecureTextProtocol {
    passwordTextField.passwordButton(vc: self)

    func passwordAction(){
        print("action")
    }
}
```

That should do the job

Answer (score 0):

You can always solve this problem with simple code, that's the way I do it.

```
    extension UITextField {
func setPasswordToggleImage(_ button: UIButton) {
    if(isSecureTextEntry){
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_password_visible"), for: .normal)
    }else{
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_password_invisible"), for: .normal)

    }
}

func enablePasswordToggle(){
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    setPasswordToggleImage(button)
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -16, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(self.frame.size.width - 25), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(25), height: CGFloat(25))
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.togglePasswordView), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.rightView = button
    self.rightViewMode = .always
}
@objc func togglePasswordView(_ sender: Any) {
    self.isSecureTextEntry = !self.isSecureTextEntry
    setPasswordToggleImage(sender as! UIButton)
}
}
```

then on viewcontroller's viewdidload just call the functions on your storyboards

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
             super.viewDidLoad()
             txtPassword.enablePasswordToggle()
             txtConfirmPassword.enablePasswordToggle()
         }
```